# There is a way to register service which is given as implicit type and has constructor with more then one parameter of primitive type

Tags: c#, dryioc

I am using dryloc and want to register service which is given as implicit type and can has constructor (or it may has not) with more then one parameters of primitive types like string or int

I have tried the following

```
var container = new Container();

Type serviceType; // some service type
Type serviceKey; // some serviceKey
var param1 = "some param1";
var param2 = "some param2";

container.Register(serviceType, Reuse.ScopedTo(serviceKey: serviceKey), 
    made: Parameters.Of.Type(_=> param1));
```

Using this API i can specify only one parameter of primitive type to be injected in constructor of service but not more. I can not use factory delegate and other similar approaches since i do not know details about type of service.

There is any way to implement this scenario?

### Update

I have resolved this problem using child scopes.

Some clarifications

- My initial example wasn't fully correct.  In fact parameters have
  different types so there is no ambiguity.
- ServiceType could has constructor which requires param1 and param2 or
  may has constructor which doesn't require them

```
var container = new Container();

Type serviceType; // some service type
Type serviceKey; // some serviceKey
var param1 = "some param1";
var param2 = 5;

container.Register(serviceType, Reuse.ScopedTo(serviceKey: serviceKey));

////

// parent scope which is created outside
IResolverContext context; 


object service = null;

using (var scope = context.OpenScope("my-child-scope"))
{
   scope.UseInstance(param1);
   scope.UseInstance(param2);

   service = scope.Resolve(serviceType);
}
```

Comment: Can I ask what you *want* to do then? If you only know the type of the parameters, not their names, how do you even know what kind of values are supposed to be injected? Forget DryIoc and its features or limits, please describe your thought process on how this *can* work.

Comment: Good note. I have updated description which shows more precisely what i want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use parameter by name: `Parameters.Of.Name(x, ...).Name(y, ...)`

Or the full blown `Made.Of` which accepts primitive constants (or any value via `Arg.Index`):

`Made.Of(() => new Blah(param1, param2, Arg.Of<RemainingParamTypeToInject>()))`

#### Update: the full example

```
using System;
using DryIoc;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container();

        // variant 1
        container.RegisterInstance("1", serviceKey: "x");
        container.RegisterInstance("2", serviceKey: "y");
        container.Register<A>(made: Parameters.Of.Name("x", serviceKey: "x").Name("y", serviceKey: "y"));

        // variant 2
        //container.Register<A>(made: Parameters.Of.Name("x", _ => "1").Name("y", _ => "2"));

        var a = container.Resolve<A>();

        Console.WriteLine(a.X + ", " + a.Y);
    }

    public class A 
    {
        public string X, Y;
        public A(string x, string y) 
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that Blah is not available. I have only typeof(Blah)

Comment: Then use `.Of.Name`. Anyway it is the same kind of unsafe as of using the position - change it and it is broken.

Comment: Here is the example with Name.Of https://dotnetfiddle.net/kRKji3